# Compile error on action for iPhone app: "error:expected ')' before ';' token"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working through the tutorials in the "Beginning iPhone Development" book. I'm on chapter 4 and I'm getting the following compile error on the "if (segment == kShowSegmentIndex)" line:

```
error:expected ')' before ';' token
```

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)toggleShowHide:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    NSInteger segment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (segment == kShowSegmentIndex) [switchView setHidden:NO]; 
    else [switchView setHidden:YES];

}
```

I've compared it with the code in the book several times and have retyped it. Sounds like this error is caused by improper brace placement. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which line of code is referenced by the compiler error?

Comment: this line: if (segment == kShowSegmentIndex) [switchView setHidden:NO];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I figured it out. The error was in a completely different section. Figures. :)

I wrote "#define kShowSegmentIndex 0;" instead of
"#define kShowSegmentIndex 0".
Apparently I should have left off the semicolon.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That was my guess, dangit! :-) For completeness, you should accept this answer so the question isn't a loose end.

Comment: I'm just starting out on Obj-C development, too. This helped me break a day long deadlock. Thanks!

-It's always the syntax errors that kill you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this webpage:
http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/991-uisegmentcontrol-help.html

It looks like you're not pulling in the definition of kShowSegmentIndex which is defined in a different file that you'll need to include in the class you're working on. Check page 74 of your book.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment definitely helped me get the right answer.

Comment: Thank you!  I had completely missed that line.  :-)